# Redis get or create?

Tags: redis

I want to use Redis as a random seed cache. When I want the value for a key, if nothing's there yet, I'll produce a random string and store it for later reuse.

How do I perform an atomic `GET EXISTING OR SET AND RETURN THIS VALUE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use SETNX to try and set the value first. Then the GET would give you the existing value or the new one you tried to set.

`SETNX key value`

This may return 0 or 1 if you care to know if this is a new value

Comment: If you want to set expiration time you will have to use `SET` command with `NX` parameter, which does the same. E.g. `SET <key> <value> NX EX <seconds>` (https://redis.io/commands/set)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no single command that can do this. Using `MULTI` and `WATCH`:

First:

```
GET key
```

If `null`, then:

```
WATCH key
MULTI
    SET key value
EXEC
```

If `[null]` (indicating the transaction aborted), the key was created in the meantime and must exist by now:

```
GET key
```